# Issue in opening word documents of office 365 enterprise version opening in client application - sharepoint server 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

We have Sharepoint Server 2013, users have issues like Not loading or freezing when they scroll or edit documents in client application.

Tried:

1. Updating word in their laptops with latest updates.
2. Cleared the following folders in the local machine, as they are the folders for the OfficeFileCache: `C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OfficeFileCache`
3. Closed all office documents.
4. Tried opening documents but still same, however most of the documents has lot of comments and review features.

Answer (score 0):

For the issues not loading or freezing when they scroll or edit documents in client application. I recommend checking this hardware requirement to see if the client is stuttered by a low server configuration.

You can refer to this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-software-requirements-2013